# Configuring Security for an S3 for Presigned Post?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Continuing my adventure in AWS, Uploading The File, I am just going to come out and ask it. What is the proper way to configure the security settings for an S3 bucket intended to be the endpoint for a presigned post file upload?

Currently I have created an IAM user with full S3 permissions which can generate the presigned post in response to a get request via an AWS Lambda function. However if I have the block all privacy setting enabled when I use the post I get access denied. If I turn off block all it works but I am worried about security.

So I will just ask, what is the proper way to configure the security settings for an S3 bucket intended to be the endpoint for a presigned post file upload?

Comment: If you enabled Block Public Access and your upload failed then presumably it's because your upload attempted to make the object public. Review how you're uploading to S3, in particular any ACLs.

Comment: No permissions are required when using a pre-signed URL, because the signature grants the permissions of the IAM entity that generated the URL. I agree with @jarmod -- it sounds like the upload process is attempting to change the ACL, which is currently blocked by S3 Block Public Access. If you play with those settings, which particular setting is the one that makes the upload possible (it would only be 1 or 2 of the settings related to ACLs, and not the ones related to Bucket Policies).

Comment: Ok, let me ask this then, if I created a IAM user called "presigner" which is not the root user and I grated it full s3 access in the IAM policy, do I also have to grant it resource access to the specific bucket via the bucket ACL?  Is this done in the "Access control list" settings or the "Bucket policy"?